# Tuleap Menus "admin" tab is missing

Tags: tuleap

[IMG: Tuleap Admin Tab Missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx4VT.jpg)

i am  having problem in accessing the admin tab, can any one tell me how to resolve this problem , it all happened when my colleague has created new project and made some changes in the permission setting, now i couldn't find the admin tab in tuleap admin panel. Please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your project admin permissions have been removed then I think you will need to get another project admin or the Tuleap site admin to grant you admin rights again.

I don't think you will be able to do it yourself as it wouldn't be very secure.

I hope this helps